# Matlab: Color of legend doesn't fit plot

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I am writing a script, which imports several sample files. Afterwards it calculates ratios of different elements and save them in a double-array. I am plotting the first column of this file for all the sample files into one plot. Which is working well. But the legends causes trouble. I want, that it includes the filenames of the sample files. But the color of the legend doesnt fit. I give you here parts of my code. Because I think the calculations are not interesting for you.

```
directory_name=uigetdir('','Ordner mit Messungen auswählen'); 
[nur_file_name,pfad]=uigetfile({'*.csv','csv-files (*.csv)';'*.*','all Files'},...
    'Die csv-Files der Proben oeffnen (probe_001.csv=',[directory_name '/'], 'Multiselect', 'on'); 
nur_file_name=cellstr(nur_file_name); 
nur_file_name=sort(nur_file_name);
filename=strcat(pfad,nur_file_name);
anzahl_files=size(filename,2); 

for xy=1:anzahl_files
    fid_in=fopen(char(filename(xy)),'r');
```

This part above import several files and saves the filename. To handle the filename easier, I changed it to a string array (1 x number of files) with the name filename_s.

Now I do some calculations (shown below). In the end I have for all measurement files a double array called "Ratio". I try to plot it with the legend includig the filenames:

```
    tmpImport = importdata(filename{xy},','); 
element_RL = tmpImport.colheaders;
element_RL=string(element_RL);
intens_RL=tmpImport.data;
[anzahl_runs,anzahl_elemente]=size(intens_RL);

for k=1:anzahl_elemente
    Background(k)=mean(intens_RL(:,k)); %
    Sigma(k)=std(intens_RL(:,k)); 
end
SP_limit=Background+(4*Sigma); 

[~, PosSr87] = ismember('87Sr+', element_RL);
SpalteSr87(:,1)=intens_RL(:,PosSr87);
[~, PosSr86] = ismember('86Sr+', element_RL);
SpalteSr86(:,1)=intens_RL(:,PosSr86);

is_SP = intens_RL > SP_limit;
intens_RL(is_SP)=1;  
intens_RL(~is_SP)=0;   

anzahl_runs1=size(intens_RL,1);
id = true(anzahl_runs1,1) ; 
for k=1:anzahl_runs1
    if any (intens_RL(k,:)==1)
        Ratio(k,1)=SpalteSr87(k,:)/SpalteSr86(k,:);
            id(k) = 0 ; 
    end
 
end

filename_s = matlab.lang.makeValidName(nur_file_name);
filename_s=string(nur_file_name);

   
%Plot: 
[NumRows1 NumCols1]=size(Ratio);
    figure(1)
    title('Proben 87Sr/86Sr');
    xlabel('Partikel');
    ylabel('87Sr/86Sr');
    for p=1:anzahl_files
        h(p)= scatter(1:NumRows1, Ratio(:,1));
        legendtext{p} = filename_s(1,p);
        hold on
    end
    legend(h, legendtext)
    end
```

Plot works, filenames in the legend works but the colours are not fitting. Please be aware that i delete some parts of the code, so some for loops makes sense if there is more ;-). I appreciate any help. Thank you really much. And please forgive if something is not the right term, I dont work with matlab so long.

Comment: Can you add a [mre] please

Comment: @AnderBiguri I added some parts above from the calculation.

Comment: Please create a [mre]